# ThreeJS - Keep object in Camera view at all times

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using threejs in a project where I need to keep a basic object in my scene just in front of the camera, whichever way the camera is pointed.  I am using the Orbit Controls plugin for movement and want to move the object around the scene so it is always in the middle of the camera view (same distance away all the time).

I am a relative newcomer to threejs so am not sure how to approach this - thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering your scene, you need to update the position of your object by placing it in front of the camera, for that you can use ***camera.position*** and ***camera.getWorldDirection()***, then do the math to compute what should be the position of your object.